# Passing value and ID from Request.POST

Tags: python, django, post

I am trying to have a website with multiple input type ="text" fields which as a default have values from database in them. 
Goal is to have X input types where X=number of entries in database and one extra input type box to add a new entry.

The problem is that if user edits a textfield and hits submit, Request.POST['event'] returns only the new value, not the id of the box that has been edited,
This is my current code:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in event %}
<form method ='POST'> {% csrf_token%}
    <input type="text" name = "event" id="event{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{choice.txt}}"><br>
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Zapisz'/>
</form>
{% endfor %}

<form method ='POST'> {% csrf_token%}
    {{form.as_p}}<br>
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Zapisz'/>
</form>
```

and views.py:

```
def rpg_create(request):

    try:
        event = get_list_or_404(Event)
    except:
        event = ""

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            Adjusted_event = request.POST['event']
            print (Adjusted_event)
        except:
            pass

        form = RpgForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form)
            form.save()
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'event': event
                    }
        return redirect('/rpgmaker', context)
    else:
        form = RpgForm()

        context = {
            'form': form,
            'event': event
                    }
        return render(request,"rpgmaker/rpg.html",context)
```

Comment: In the code you post, a form end tag is missing ; what is the role of your first form? Why did you need yo display you entries in a form?

Comment: yes, this has been doubled by mistake. That was just an element of choice, I want user to be able to see his previous entries and be able to edit them in a quickest manner possible.